# Upgrade an existing Padrino project

Tags: rubygems, sinatra, padrino

I have a project that I created using Padrino 11.2 a few months ago.

Since then, Padrino 11.4 has been released, and I did a 'gem install padrino' to pull down the latest version.

However, when I go to an old project folder and type in 'padrino v' it is still saying 11.2.  If I go to a clean folder and type 'padrino v' it says 11.4.

Is there a way to 'upgrade' the older project folders without having to recreate them from scratch?

I've tried 'bundle install' etc. but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have Padrino 11.2 locked in Gemfile.lock since it was already installed.
You need to run `bundle update padrino` inside your old directory, or specify version in Gemfile like `gem "padrino", "0.11.4"` and then run `bundle install`

Comment: Thank you Ivan - I didn't realise the Gemfile had locked in the version.  I changed it as per your instructions, then ran 'bundle update' and 'bundle install' and it is now reporting the correct version - Thank You.